# I want to convert the content of my PDF file to JSON data with proper formatting using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, webdriver-io

I want to convert a PDF with a content like the one below:

```
PACKAGES
  In-Transit
    Item: Package A
    Weight: 10
    Price: 100

    Item: Package B
    Weight: 10
    Price: 500

  Delivered
    Item: Package C
    Weight: 10
    Price: 300

  To be packed
    Item: Package D
    Weight: 10
    Price: 600
```

I want to have a JSON results like this:

```
 {
  "packages":
  [
   {
    "item": "package a",
    "weight":10,
    "price": 100,
    "status": "in-transit"
   },
   {
    "item": "package b",
    "weight":10,
    "price": 500,
    "status": "in-transit"
   }
  ]
 }
```

I am browsing some npm packages and open sources but nothing renders the output that I want. I hope someone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The above content are the example content of my PDF. it is simply a text exported as PDF.